# Wait until method completes before next method?

Tags: php

I have a class that uploads images:

```
$myClass->upload();
nextMethod();
```

In this upload method a (AWS S3) promise is executed:

```
$promise->then(function() { echo "Done\n"; }, function() { echo "Not Done\n"; });
```

How can I make it so that nextMethod is not called until the promise is completed?

Comment: PHP isn't asynchronous so you shouldn't need promises at all.

Comment: But the AWS SDK is. I need to wait for the images to upload before moving on. So in the 'then' how can I callback to my main class?

Comment: have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html): there is a `wait()` function for synchronously tasks... i.e. `$result = $promise->wait();`

Comment: It looks like you're not following AWS's guidelines for the syntax or there is code that you have left out of your example.

Comment: Raphael Müller the above does use the wait function, then upon completion then is called. How can I callback to the parent class in the then method?

Answer (score 0):

Because the promise is asynchronous by default (i.e. only registering the callback to be called when the upload actually completes), the only way to do that is to execute all the logic from the promise success callback. (i.e. the `nextMethod()`) If you require the use of variables from the parent scope, pass them to the `use` language construct.

```
$promise->then(function() { echo "Done\n"; nextMethod(); }, function() { echo "Not Done\n"; });
```